# Make SQLite abort on first error (and sing songs)

Tags: sqlite

I wanted to name this post *Make SQLite abort on first error* but StackOverflow's AI overlords decided it doesn't fit their conception of intelligent human behavior. For the record, I was googling exactly that, but perhaps even Google AI considered my question unworthy and didn't bother to help me. Mods, feel free to change the title according to what your AI bosses desire (if you can figure it out).

---

I have this script

```
create if not exists table entries (
    id integer primary key,
    start datetime not null,
    end datetime not null
);

delete from entries;
insert into entries values (1, '2018-08-01 10:00', '2018-08-01 15:00');
insert into entries values (2, '2018-08-01 17:00', '2018-08-01 20:00');
insert into entries values (1, '2018-08-02 19:00', '2018-08-02 00:00');
insert into entries values (1, '2018-08-03 00:00', '2018-08-03 04:00');
insert into entries values (1, '2018-08-03 14:00', '2018-08-03 18:00');
```

There is a mistake in `create` statement. When I run the script I get

```
% sqlite3 db.sqlite3 <ddl.sql
Error: near line 1: near "if": syntax error
Error: near line 7: no such table: entries
Error: near line 8: no such table: entries
Error: near line 9: no such table: entries
Error: near line 10: no such table: entries
Error: near line 11: no such table: entries
Error: near line 12: no such table: entries
```

How do I make SQLite exit executing the script on first error it encounters? I'm looking for equivalent of `set -e` in Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html), it looks like you can turn on the dot command `.bail`.

> .bail on|off           Stop after hitting an error.  Default OFF

[See also](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/using-sqlite/9781449394592/re50.html) - O'Reilly Using Sqlite

**Edit**

To exit, you can use the `.exit` dot command.

Comment: That doesn't make the shell exit on error. (It was my first suggestion too until I tested it).

Comment: Then that should be the question, not `exiting executing the script`. I have no way to test, but using the `.exit` should work

Comment: "How do I make SQLite exit executing the script on first error it encounters?" is pretty clear. (.bail on/-bail might do what OP wants, actually. On more testing it does make sqlite3 exit with status 1 when redirecting input from a file with a error; I had just tried typing directly into it)

Comment: When I read that, it seemed like he wanted the script to stop running, not exit the shell.

Comment: @CodeMonkey That's correct. My mind is now elsewhere, but I remember I also wanted `sqlite3` to exit with non-zero exit code if an error occurs. I was not talking about interactive sqlite3 shell but script usage.